# Querying a MarkLogic 7 SPARQL endpoint

Tags: curl, sparql, marklogic

This works to query a `Virtuoso SPARQL` endpoint:

> curl --url [http host port]/sparql --data-urlencode query@all.q

all.q is this:

> select * where {?s ?p ?o}

This does not work to query a `MarkLogic 7 SPARQL` endpoint (I'm using the example in 5.3.6.1 of the **MarkLogic 7 Semantics Developer's Guide**, p. 112, as my guide):

> curl -H "Content-type: application/sparql-query" -H "Accept:
>   application/sparql-results+xml" --data-binary '@./all.q' [http host
>   port]/v1/graphs/sparql

The result is:

```
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#"><head/><results/></sparql>
```

The query works fine from the `MarkLogic 7` **qconsole**. Is the documentation slightly out of sync with the software, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Which release of MarkLogic are you using?

Are you sure your app server is connected to the right database?

What about security? You're probably running qconsole as an admin user. The curl request will run as whatever user you specify, either via `curl --digest -u` or via the app server config for authentication and default user. If that user doesn't have permission to see the data, that would explain the empty results. For example have you configured the app server to run all requests as `nobody`?

I was able to set up a REST endpoint on a 7.0-3 instance and access it from curl. I used the example from https://docs.marklogic.com/sem:graph-insert to insert some data. The same data showed up using your query via qconsole and via curl. The result of the curl request was:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="s"/>
    <variable name="p"/>
    <variable name="o"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="s">
        <uri>urn:isbn:9780080540160</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="p">
        <uri>http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="o">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Query XML,XQuery, XPath, and SQL/XML in context</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>`

Or in JSON, using `application/sparql-results+json`:

`{
  "head": {
    "vars": [
      "s",
      "p",
      "o"
    ]
  },
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "s": {
          "type": "uri",
          "value": "urn:isbn:9780080540160"
        },
        "p": {
          "type": "uri",
          "value": "http:\/\/purl.org\/dc\/elements\/1.1\/title"
        },
        "o": {
          "type": "literal",
          "value": "Query XML,XQuery, XPath, and SQL\/XML in context",
          "datatype": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema#string"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: I'm using the same version of MarkLogic as you. Authentication is application-level (basic results in an authentication error) and the default user is nobody. I successfully inserted the data as you did, above, and can see it in qconsole, but not via curl; the response remains empty.

Comment: I solved the problem by making the default user mark(admin). Thanks for your response.

Comment: The `nobody` user almost certainly doesn't have permission to see the documents you inserted. I'd fix that by changing the server to digest auth and using `curl --digest -u user:password`. But you could also change the default user to your admin user, or whatever login you used with qconsole.